# How to implement a SOAP Proxy for ASP.NET site?

Tags: asp.net, soap, proxy

I have an ASP.NET (2.0) site that utilizes SOAP to (Auth.svc) to authenticate a user to a 3rd party site and generate a token back. PReviously it has worked flawlessly but recently the application moved to a new datacenter with a more restrictive firewall and when trying to access the Auth.svc's on the 3rd party sites it times out after about 45 seconds with a cannot connect error.

I was speaking with the firewall team and they said that if I implemented a web proxy then it could work.

I have no idea where to begin on this. I've been reading and researching online but haven't found any conclusive answers. This link -- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipfire/#Resources is the closest I've found that relates to my situation.

Site is written in ASP.NET (2.0 framework) on a W2K8R2 server running IIS 7.5. Anyone have any idea on where to start to look to try to implement a solution that will let me access these 3rd party sites via SOAP? (Is that question crafted properly?)

Thanks.

Comment: "I implemented a web proxy then it could work" - I don't see why that would make any difference. Do they mean just caching the result? I don't think you'd want to do that. If they suggested a proxy is that because they have specific connection restrictions e.g. from only a small set of IP addresses? You need to get a clearer idea of what the problem is and why they think a proxy will solve it.